# Alfresco Share 3.3 - How do I get my new custom type to appear in the Create Content drop down?

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I have created a custon type. I can create a Plain Text content item in Alfresco Share and Convert Type to my custom type (`my:foo`). So far so good.

But, how can I add my custom type to the Create Content drop down?

I tried this by creating `$TOMCAT/shared/classes/alfresco/extension/web-client-config-custom.xml`

```
<alfresco-config>
   <config evaluator="string-compare" condition="Content Wizards">
      <content-types>
         <type name="my:foo" />
      </content-types>
   </config>
</alfresco-config>
```

But this has not helped. Any ideas?

Comment: Asked and answered in the Alfresco forums.

Comment: Jeff didn't include link -> http://forums.alfresco.com/forum/developer-discussions/alfresco-explorer-development/how-do-i-get-my-new-custom-type-appear

Answer (score 2):

You haven't specified exact version (3.3a through 3.3g), there are lots of changes from minor to minor version.

Take a look at this [topic](http://forums.alfresco.com/forum/developer-discussions/alfresco-share-development/add-own-content-types-create-content-menu), you could use some hints.

Comment: Does this help? From alfresco.log: 09:29:26,241 INFO  [org.alfresco.service.descriptor.DescriptorService] Alfresco started (Community): Current version 3.3.0 (2765) schema 4009 - Originally installed version 3.3.0 (2765) schema 4009

Comment: Look for file under path _alfresco\WEB-INF\classes\alfresco_ **\version.properties**

Comment: `version.major=3
version.minor=3
version.revision=0
version.label=
version.edition=Community
version.build=2765
version.schema=4009`
Each of these is on a fresh line, and version.label has no value.

Comment: Hm, I don't think I could help you more, I don't have that version. Sorry

Comment: How could I do this for 3.3g? Maybe I can work backwards/forwards from those instructions.

Comment: If you have option to chose versions than go for it. Though it would be wise to go for 4.2f or something like that.

Comment: My company has Enterprise 3.3.3 installed - 4.2 is not an option unfortunately. I am trying to learn how to let our business users create an XYZ content type using Share. I cant imaging there are that many differences between 3.3a - 3.3g & 3.3.3?